# No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-file

I am getting this error  "No mapping found for [@timestamp] in order to sort logstash"

My conf file

```
input { elasticsearch {
 
 hosts => ["localhost"]
 index => "employees_data"
 query => '{ "query": { "match_all": { } } }'
 scroll => "5m"
 docinfo => true}}filter {elasticsearch {
 hosts => ["localhost"]
 index => "transaction_data"
 query => "code:1"
 fields => { 
             "code"=>"Code"
             "payment" => "Payment"
             "moth"=>"Month"}}}output {elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost"]index => "join"}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of the [`sort` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-elasticsearch.html#plugins-filters-elasticsearch-sort) of the `elasticsearch` filter plugin. If unspecified, it defaults to `@timestamp:desc` and you probably don't have that field.

Just make the following change and you should be good to go:

```
filter {
    elasticsearch {
        hosts => ["localhost"]
        index => "transaction_data"
        query => "code:1"
        sort => "code:asc"                   <--- add this line
        fields => {
            "code"=>"Code"
            "payment" => "Payment"
            "moth"=>"Month"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i've two records in transaction_data but it is getting the latest one .how to get both records

Comment: You can add `result_size => 2` as well, as the default value is 1

Comment: is there any way to set in infinite or something

Comment: You can set to any number up to 10000, the default value that can be changed if necessary, but I don't see the reason in your case

Comment: is there any way to filter only one index just like in employees_data i want to filter out records from city like city :mumbai

Comment: Please ask a new question as this one is closed and your new question is pretty much unrelated to this one.

Comment: Please help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64221149/is-there-any-way-to-flatten-json-data-in-logstash